# Silverpop smtp not able to send both text and html content

Tags: java, smtp

I am using silverpop smtp for sending mail. My mail content both text and html. When i am sending mail I am able to send both and I am getting only html content. Text content is not getting through. Please help.

```
    final Message msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
final MimeBodyPart textPart= new MimeBodyPart();    
                    textPart.setContent("message1", "text/plain");        
                final MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();    
                htmlPart.setContent("message2", "text/html");    
                final Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");     
                mp.addBodyPart(textPart);    
                mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);        
                msg.setContent(mp); 
                Transport.send(msg);    
                Transport.send(msg);
```

Please help.

Comment: do you get any errors? Can we see the code which is sending the mail?

Comment: hi thanks for reply ,i am not getting any error. but i am sending that by gmail server its sending correctly and getting also

Answer (score 0):

Just because you aren't seeing both on the receiving side, doesn't mean it isn't sending both. It depends on how your email is set up. If you have it set to receive HTML, that is what you will see. If you are using text by default, you should see text. To view text, see the following:

Gmail:
Open the email you want to view as text.
Click on the arrow at the top right corner of your message. You will see a drop down menu.
Select 'Message text garbled' this will open the text version of this message.
Mail App (Mac):
Open the email you want to view as text.
Go to 'View' on the top tool bar.
Then select 'Message' and 'Plain Text Alternative'.

I got this info from http://www.mailermailer.com/support/knowledgebase/sending/kb/495

You can google your mail client if you use something different.